# building a parser in python

Tags: python

I am trying to make a parser in python which can achieve two types of functionality

```
s1 = foo()
s2 = {'k1':v1,'k2':v2}
s3 = [v1,v2,v3...]
```

I say two types... where first type is usually objects and second types are kind off like variables.
Now First one is easy..

```
def parse_string_to_command(string):
     if "foo" in string:
         #handle this.
     elif # handle s2 
     elif #condition to handle s3
```

EDIT 1:
I think I didnt clearly stated what I am trying to achive.

All I am trying to do is follows:

Everything that passes from that function is a string.. some are methods.. while others are variables.
I am just trying to handle them accordingly.

Basically this is what user will be doing

```
 > params = {"input":"foobar"}
 > foo = Foo(params)
```

Now, to handle Foo method.. I do this:

```
   if "Foo" in string:
      tokens = string.split("=")
      # I have tokens [foo,Foo(params)]

   But params is a string now..whereas it is needed to be a dictionary.
```

Now I  know i can just handle it here..inside Foo method.. but in general I want to handle these variable assignments inside parse_string_to_command function

Is it making any sense.

Comment: Clever doesn't always mean best.

Comment: @WaleedKhan: So what is the best way to robustly handle this?

Comment: @WaleedKhan Just to clarify: In programming, clever more or less never means best :) It's more or less the opposite of readability

Comment: @Fraz You haven't specified the types of functionality you need. As such the question isn't really answerable.

Comment: @WaleedKhan: What specifics.. you have a string coming in.. even if its a dictionary.. list or method.. its a string.. and i want to handle it accordingly?? def parse_string_to_command(string) :?? right

Comment: I dont get it.. whats with the negative votes..? I thought.. people are here to help each other?

Comment: Your requirements are poorly stated and there is no clear example of how you are using parse_string_to_command().  What are the valid inputs?  What do you have to distinguish in your conditional branching?  Is the problem that the types of the "string" parameter can vary (this is a bad name btw for arguments/variables)?  Should s1,s2,s3 actually be string types?  Is this purely string parsing?

Comment: In short, I don't know what it is you are trying to handle.  So the question of what's best is moot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look into using pythons [JSON](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) parser for accomplishing your goal.

```
>>> import json
>>> a = json.loads('["foo", {"bar": ["baz", null, 1.0, 2]}]')
>>> a
[u'foo', {u'bar': [u'baz', None, 1.0, 2]}]
>>> a[0]
u'foo'
>>> a[1]
{u'bar': [u'baz', None, 1.0, 2]}
>>> a[1]['bar']
[u'baz', None, 1.0, 2]
>>>>>> a[1]['bar'][0]
u'baz'
```

or if you need it completely custom... with out the intention to write a complete parser for you, I imagine using some regular expressions will help make your job easier.

```
>>> import re
>>> s1 = "foo()"
>>> s2 = "{'k1':v1,'k2':v2}"
>>> s3 = "[v1,v2,v3]"
>>> re.match('(.*?)\(\)',s1).group(1)
'foo'
>>> re.findall('\{*(.*?):(.*?)[,\}$]+',s2)
[("'k1'", 'v1'), ("'k2'", 'v2')]
>>> re.findall('\[*(.*?)[,\]$]+',s3)
['v1', 'v2', 'v3']
```

To just identify the 3 types of input strings:

```
def parse_string_to_command(s):
    if re.match('(.*?\(\))',s):
        print "This is a function"
    elif re.match('^\{.*\}$',s):
        print "This is kind of like variables 1"
    elif re.match('^\[.*\]$',s):
        print "This is kind of like variables 2"
```